Can a Healer get the Summon monster added in its spell list?
Can a Healer (miniature handbook pg. 8) get any one of these added to its spell list?
Preferably before level 5.

Summon monster (1 to 9)
Summon Nature's Ally (1 to 9)
any derivative (summon desert ally...)

Using this thread we can figure that no initiate feat, no domain, no prc...
Sandshaper might have been an option but it is dubious if the spells are added to your spell list beside not being an arcane caster. (And you need and arcane spell level, depending how you rule it a duergar level 3 could qualify).
After level 5, sovereign speaker can give the summoning domain. And I guess tere is plenty of options after that.

Nexus Method and Magical Training
This is a weird combo and only questionably works, but it might work and if it does, it might be cheaper than other options, since it gets you all of the summon monster spells for two feats.
Nexus Method from Dragon vol. 319 effectively gives you an option similar to the spontaneous casting of the cleric or druid classes, converting a prepared spell spontaneously into a summon monster spell of the same level.
There are two potential problems with this:

It doesn’t add the spells to your spell list as requested in the question. You can cast the spells, but you don’t technically have them on your list and that might matter (for instance, you wouldn’t get the ability to use spell-completion or spell-trigger  items without Use Magic Device from this).

The feat requires “Ability to prepare and cast arcane spells.” The healer, obviously, prepares and casts divine spells. Despite the prerequisite, Nexus Method’s benefit isn’t restricted to arcane spells, so if you can qualify, you’re golden, but qualifying will take some doing.


The first problem is just something you’ll have to decide for yourself, depending on your exact needs; there isn’t any way to “solve” it if it doesn’t work for you.
The other problem does have a solution: Magical Training from Player’s Guide to Faerûn can (as long as you have Int 10) allow you to prepare and cast a few cantrips as a wizard, which meets the requirement. But that solution has its own problem:

Magical Training has a prerequisite of “Elf (Evereska or Evermeet) or human (Halruaa or Nimbral)” while Nexus Method has “Region: Solnor Compact.” If you’re unfamiliar, Evereska, Evermeet, Halruaa, and Nimbral are in the Forgotten Realms, and Solnor Compact is in Greyhawk. Meeting both requirements at the same time is... dubious. RAW-legal, but you’ll want to check with your DM on several points.
The explanation of regional feats in Dragon vol. 319 allows you to become familiar enough with a new region to take feats for that region later on:

As characters travel, they may learn regional feats from new geographic regions. After 1st level, every 2 ranks in Knowledge (local) allow you to select feats from another region.

(Dragon vol. 319, pg. 56)
However, this requires a bit of a backstory. Regional feats were introduced in the Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, a 3e book. In that book, we had a similar rule:

You may even learn feats from a new region altogether, whether or not you belong to an encouraged class for that region. After 1st level, each 2 ranks in Knowledge (local) you have allow you to select feats from a single region (other than your home region, if applicable).

(Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting, pg. 28)
Then Player’s Guide to Faerûn—the 3.5e update to Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting and the source of Magical Training—has this to say:

Regional Feats and Previously Published Material
The region system here updates and replaces the region system and regional feats described in the Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting. However, additional regions and regional feats have also appeared in Races of Faerûn and Unapproachable East. Any feat from either of those publications that includes a “Region” line should be considered a regional feat and is subject to the same selection restrictions as other feats with the “Regional” description.
The region system in this book limits each character to one and only one regional feat that must be selected at 1st level. This rule replaces the one on page 28 of the Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting that allows a character to learn another regional feat for each 2 ranks in Knowledge (local) she has. The regional feats presented herein are designed with the intent that a character has access to only one. Allowing a character to choose more than one may unbalance the system.

(Player’s Guide to Faerûn, pg. 33)
So the Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting rule was replaced in the 3.5e update by the Player’s Guide to Faerûn rule. And we need Player’s Guide to Faerûn to be in play, because that’s where the Magical Training feat we need is (Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting also had a Magical Training feat, but it works differently and won’t work for Nexus Method, even if we ignore the 3.5e update). And while Player’s Guide to Faerûn provides updated versions of Forgotten Realms Campaign Setting regional feats to justify the “just one” rule, it doesn’t do the same with regional feats from Races of Faerûn or Unapproachable East—but still explicitly includes them in the “just one” limit.
RAW, none of this matters to Dragon vol. 319 at all; nothing in Player’s Guide to Faerûn really applies there. Player’s Guide to Faerûn is the 3.5e update to a lot of Forgotten Realms material, but it’s not a 3.5e update of Dragon vol. 319—that’s was written for 3.5e to begin with, and actually came out two months after Player’s Guide to Faerûn, so it’s not “previously published material” at all. Even the restriction from Player’s Guide to Faerûn that you only have one [Regional] feat, that would apply to Magical Training, doesn’t technically matter: Dragon vol. 319 doesn’t use [Regional] (just as the 3e FR regional feats didn’t, which Player’s Guide to Faerûn had to explicitly address).
But it’s definitely a weird situation, and one you should discuss with the DM. At the end of the day, Dragon vol. 319 did not think Nexus Method and the other feats in the article were “extra powerful” and that “a character [with] more than one may unbalance the system,” so I would allow it happily, but ultimately being a responsible player includes being open and transparent about these issues.
Worse, even if the Dragon vol. 319 rules are allowed to stand for those feats, you’d have to be someone from the Forgotten Realms who somehow became extremely familiar with a region of Greyhawk somehow. RAW, all this takes is 2 ranks in Knowledge (local), but again, a weird situation that should be checked with the DM whether that’s allowed and if so what it implies about your character.


If you can’t take both Nexus Method and Magical Training, but Nexus Method works for you, a single-level dip in wizard or wu jen (Complete Arcane) would allow you to take Nexus Method and then apply it to healer. This is obviously suboptimal, but it would work, and work as early as 2nd (this does mean starting with the arcane class and switching to healer later). Both wizard and wu jen have half-decent things to offer from a dip (e.g. abrupt jaunt, rapid summoning, initiative rerolls, bonus feats), so it’s not the worst thing in the world. You could even consider mystic theurge with Precocious Apprentice (Complete Arcane, pg. 181) if you wanted to.
Domains—most notably Summoner
Domains are one of the most common ways to add spells to a divine spellcaster.
Summon monster
The best domain to get, without a doubt, is Summoner. Summoner domain grants summon monster I, II, III, V, and VII.
Summon monster I is also available from the Portal domain. Summon monster IV, VI, and VIII are not available from any domains, and though summon monster IX is found on several, in every case it’s limited to monsters with a particular subtype, so you don’t get access to the full list.
Summon nature’s ally
Options for summon nature’s ally are even more limited: Animal domain gets IV and VIII, but can only summon animals, and the Fey domain gets IX (properly, no arbitrary limitations), but the other levels aren’t available.
Other summoning spells
And then we get into the more niche stuff: Sandstorm’s summon desert ally only appears at IX, on the Sand domain. Frostburn’s conjure ice beast line isn’t quite the same (they’re creation spells instead of summoning), but anyway that’s not available on any domains either. And the summon undead spells (printed in several books, but only I through V, there are no summon undead VI, VII, VIII, or IX spells) don’t appear on any domains.
Getting a domain
Per the above, we probably only really want the Summoner domain.
Unfortunately, doing so by 5th is a challenge: they’re mostly available via prestige classes, which are rarely accessible before 6th, and most prestige classes give you a domain from a fairly limited selection—and most of them don’t offer anything with summoning spells. You’re looking at basically contemplative (Complete Divine) and/or sovereign speaker (Faiths of Eberron) that actually help.
Contemplative is pretty much the better one: entry is super-easy, it gets full spellcasting, you get any domain you want at 1st and another at 6th, it’s great. The problem is, it requires 13 ranks: you’re not getting Summoner domain until ECL 11th at best without extreme cheese.
Sovereign speaker is a really neat prestige class that has some really great flavor, and it’s certainly not bad: you get 9 domains (!) in 9 levels (!!!). Problems abound here, though: you need to already have a domain to get in, you miss out on spellcasting at 1st (and again at 6th if you stick around), and most of all, while sovereign speaker does get the Summoner domain you want, the only other domain that helps at all is Animal, and that helps pretty minimally, so the whole “domain every level” thing is kind of wasted on you (though certainly is pretty nice in general for a healer). But it does have one huge advantage over contemplative: you can easily get that domain at 6th. Still doesn’t meet your desire for getting it before 5th, but it’s a lot better than contemplative’s 13th. But you have to figure out how to get in, which requires some domain, which probably means going with some other prestige class to get some other domain first and probably only getting Summoner at ECL 7th at best.
So how do you do better than that? You’re basically looking at domain draught from Magic Item Compendium. It lets you just prepare the domain’s spells as if the spells were on your list, but it’s also a consumable, single-use item that gives you the domain for just 24 hours—and costs 3300 gp. Still, you can afford 3300 gp a couple times at 5th.
For completeness’s sake, there’s also:

A domain icon (Faiths of Eberron) allows you to swap a prepared spell for the spell from the corresponding domain 3/day, which is pretty good but not the same as actually having the spells on your list. It also costs 10,000 gp, which isn’t really affordable by 5th.

A domain staff (Complete Champion) is much worse, costing 36,000 gp and allowing you to swap in each spell from the domain only once per day.



I’ll consider non-domain options in a little bit, but figured getting five summon monster spells for one feat was a pretty good start.

The Catalogues only grant the domain's granted ability (hence from the domain Summoner (SpC 281) a +2 caster level on calling and summoning conjuration spells) not the domain's spell list. To get any spellcasting from the Catalogues, you have to visit the Catalogues (!) then you get limited ask-the-DM-how-it-works spellcasting according to the domain. (If that last point is the answer's point, the spellcasting ambiguity should be more explicit.)

@HeyICanChan I missed that, will revise!

You might want to mention (if only to dismiss) the Nexus Method feat from Dragon #319. It would require an arcane caster dip or another feat to fulfill the prerequisites, but it arguably gives access to all Summon Monster spells, and certainly any available in other ways, i.e. through the Summoner Domain.
